# Can't run anything from the terminal

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-framework-version

/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.200/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1220,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks.

So what to should I do am just trying to write simple stuff in the terminal.
Also what come to mind is that I installed Mono separately from Visual Studio 2019.Could this be an issue?

Comment: Please give us more context - in particular, it seems odd that you're running Visual Studio if you're also seeing references to paths such as `/usr/local/share/...` (as VS is Windows-only, and the path is one I'd expect on Linux).

Comment: Are you writing the “simple stuff” to what framework version? If 4.7.2 then you need to run it with Mono, not .NET 6

Comment: So I am running it on a Mac and I installed mono framework for Unity, but I also installed the .Net 6. So how do I use one and not the other?